# Connection between Green's function and density Matrix

Tags: density-operator, greens-functions, open-quantum-systems

There are different approaches to solve the many-body problem of an open-quantum system.  Just to mention two methods, there are the Equations Of Motion (EOM) and the Hierarchical Equations Of Motion (HEOM) methods. While the first one focuses on solving the Green´s function of the system, the latter solves for the density matrix of the system. I am wondering which is the equation that relates let's say the Retarded Greens function and the density matrix. In particular, my motivation is to understand how to compute the spectral function $A(\omega)$ from the density matrix.

Comment: Hi! It would be helpful if you could define your terms a bit more precisely (especially Green function and the spectral function).

Comment: If I am guessing their meaning correctly $A(\omega)$ is a a Fourier transform of an unequal time correlation function and therefore cannot be calculated from the density matrix. One instead has to invoke the quantum regression theorem or similar.